# Export Connection Configuration from RDC Manager

Tags: remote-desktop

I am trying to export connection groups [.RDG files] configured in RDC [Remote Desktop Connection] Manager. Is there a way to do this?

***N.B.*** I could not get hold of the file in the file system.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just figured it out myself. Just select the group, Choose File -> Save As -> filename.rdg. :-)

Answer (score 9):

Although when you use the Open/Save commands in RDC Manager it shows the path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Remote Desktop Connection Manager
```

When you actually search for .rdg files across the pc, you will find that these are in fact stored in a virtual store.

Try access the following location:

```
C:\Users\Your User\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\Remote Desktop Connection Manager
```

From the VirtualStore location, you can copy and paste the files to make it easy to transfer between different pcs.

Answer (score 6):

If you try right-clicking on the group you will only see the SAVE option. The interesting thing is, it appears that your saving a "file" as the file explorer dialog will come up. If you save the file, (say: testRDCPgroup.rdg) and browse to the default directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Remote Desktop Connection Manager; you will not find that file (!). If you go back into RDCM and choose OPEN, and browse to that location, you can OPEN the "ghost" file [I just double checked that show hidden files and operating system files is enabled, so I can see both].

This took me about an hour to figure out too, if you select the group and go into the MENU you can do the SAVE AS; which will allow you to save the .rdg file to a different location.

The .rdg file created from the menu opens beautifully on another computer using file->Open.
One of those things that is EASILY overlooked and will have you feeling like it's your first day on the job.

Answer (score 0):

How to Export your RDP connections -

> C:\Users(*Your USER
>   PROFILE*)\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftRemoteDesktopPreview_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\RemoteDesktopData\LocalWorkspace

1) follow the above directory

> C:\Users(*Your USER
>   PROFILE*)\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftRemoteDesktopPreview_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\RemoteDesktopData\LocalWorkspace

2) Copy the Folder called Connections

> C:\Users\CYBERPOWER\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftRemoteDesktopPreview_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\RemoteDesktopData\LocalWorkspace**connections**

NB: the file is locked try to copy in SAFE MODE or USE Backup software to backup this folder - it might not work if you copy this folder just like is...

Import - Make sure you have downloaded the app on your new device https://www.microsoft.com/en-za/p/microsoft-remote-desktop/9wzdncrfj3ps?rtc=1&activetab=pivot:overviewtab
or 
https://aka.ms/rdapps

1) past & replace in new location

> C:\Users\CYBERPOWER\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftRemoteDesktopPreview_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\RemoteDesktopData\LocalWorkspace\connections

NB:it might say you do not have permission...
give your folder Permission and try again.

You can just log out and log back into your Profile and this will take affect.

NOTE: This is for the Remote Desktop Client. https://aka.ms/rdapps